# Hive window function range over timestamp column in nanosecond

Tags: sql, hive, window

I have a hive table containing a timestamp column, an ID column and an email column like below:

```
Insert_tm                 ID   email
2020-04-01 02:03:05:857   1    xxx@mail.com
2020-04-01 02:03:05:879   2    xxx@mail.com
2020-04-01 03:05:08:678   3    xxy@mail.com
2020-04-01 03:05:09:789   4    xxy@mail.com
```

I am trying to calculate the number of unique ID that sharing the same Email addresses before (include) each row within one hour based on insert_tm. I am expecting to get the below results:

```
Insert_tm                 ID   email           Count
2020-04-01 02:03:05:857   1    xxx@mail.com    1
2020-04-01 02:03:05:879   2    xxx@mail.com    2
2020-04-01 03:05:08:678   3    xxy@mail.com    1
2020-04-01 03:05:09:789   4    xxy@mail.com    2
```

My solution is to use hive window function like below:

```
select insert_tm, id, email, count(id) over (partition by email order by insert_tm range between 3600 preceding and current row) as count
```

But I get the below result:

```
Insert_tm                 ID   email           Count
2020-04-01 02:03:05:857   1    xxx@mail.com    2
2020-04-01 02:03:05:879   2    xxx@mail.com    2
2020-04-01 03:05:08:678   3    xxy@mail.com    1
2020-04-01 03:05:09:789   4    xxy@mail.com    2
```

the count for ID = 1 is 2 instead of 1. This happens when there is another record having the insert_tm difference within 1 second.

Is there anyway to get the correct count even in nanosecond level?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit of speculation in this answer.

First, [timestamps can be converted to numbers in two different ways](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types):

- to integers (for Unix epoch seconds)
- to floats (for Unix epoch with fractions of a second)

The window frame in Hive only accepts a [number](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics).  However -- and this is where the speculation is -- the documentation does not specify the type of the number.

I think the "number" is really an integer.  This -- in turn -- results in an implicit conversion of the `timestamp` to an integer.  As integers, the first two rows have the same value -- so both get counted.

I suspect that an explicit conversion to a floating point type will fix the problem:

```
count(id) over (partition by email
                order by cast(insert_tm as double)
                range between 3600 preceding and current row
               ) as count
```